# How do you change the brush of an existing grease pencil stroke?

Tags: grease-pencil

If I draw a stroke with the grease pencil, and the brush is set to "Pencil", how can I change that stroke so it has a different brush, ie "Ink Pen"?

I cannot find how to do this in the UI, is there one? If it is not possible via the UI, how about from a Python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once performed, the stroke is transformed into a serie of vertices. Every vertex has attributes of location, strenght and thickness, that can be edited using the brushes in sculpt mode; the smooth brush can be edited affecting location, thickness and strenght in any combination.

A different material as line, fill or both can be assigned.

There is no way to turn back to the stroke itself and have it assigned to another brush, but in your example turning from pencil to ink is simply adjusting strenght.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Josh. A brush is more than just strength values (as I'm sure you know), for example it might have a texture. So there is no way in the UI to assign a different brush.  I could not find a way to access the info via the Python APIs either.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the stroke informations after the conversion in vertices are gone.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186770/changing-the-grease-pencil-brush-from-the-api?rq=1 Maybe this Pythoon code can be useful to read a stroke and rewrite it with a different brush.